# My links wander out of their (resizable) parent area

Tags: css, resize, parent

I do not know why the div Link1 is not keyed to the div bg1.

I think its position should be staying at its specified place in the picture, even when the picture is resized. Instead, it is keyed to the whole page and moves away from the picture when I resize the page.

Here is a skeleton of the page:

http://www.jacamart.de

```
<div id="bg1">
    <img src="bg.jpg">
    <a href="feld2.htm" target="feld" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
        <div id="link1"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
#bg1 img {
    width: 100%;
    Position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#link1 {
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 5%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: 0%;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index: 4;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#link1:hover {
    opacity:0.1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=10);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: Show code, a lot of people don't want to go to random websites. They smell funny.

Comment: You have the links as a background image which is wrong. You have div inside links which is also wrong and even if it was right, you need position relative to the link so that the child element can be positioned absolute. Why don't you create a menu on the right with the menu elements as images?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Antony: better this way?   @ Nale: why is it wrong to want to have the links in the bg? I mean, it seems unpractical at the moment, but it allows for nice typographic design. I do not want the links to float over the title in this specific design. Unfortunately, i do not understand the "you need position relative to the link so that the child element can be positioned absolute" part of your comment. Could you help me some more and make a newbie-friendly explanation?

Comment: I would advise that you forget about having the graphics scale with the width of the window, maybe other people will disagree but I don't know any website that does that - and for good reason I feel. If I want to view Stack Overflow in a small window I don't want everything to be 20% of the size of if I have it full screen. If you keep everything fixed size then it eliminates your problem too.